# Stopping an Animation Drawable

Tags: android, android-animation

I have this animation with the xml below inside my activity. Do I need to stop it when the activity gets destroyed or not?

```
    backAnime = (AnimationDrawable) findViewById(R.id.activity_main).getBackground();
    backAnime.setEnterFadeDuration(2000);
    backAnime.setExitFadeDuration(3000);
    backAnime.start();



<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/homegradient"
    android:duration="8000"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/homegradient2"
    android:duration="8000"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/homegradient3"
    android:duration="8000"/>

</animation-list>
```

Comment: no need it, if activity is got destroyed.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar not even in orientation?

Comment: on orientation change, onCreate() will be called again. so i think you no need it.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar Im concerned about memory leaks if i dont stop it manually

Comment: yes, if you concerned about memory leak then you have to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, stop it in the "onStop()" method, by doing this it will also cover those cases when the app goes in the background (where onDestroy() is not called).